# How to create a vertical header with right justified text and a colored background?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a vertical header in Bootstrap and I'm having some issues with it. I'm learning Bootstrap so please be patient with me.

I created a JSFiddle page so that you can see what the problem is and also what I am trying to achieve. The code is here below. However, if you look at the JSFiddle page please make the results screen as large as you can. If you do then you should see the desired result I am trying to achieve. A vertical header that has two rows of justified text to the right (or top) along with a bluish background color behind the text.  If you then make the results screen smaller then you can see where lies the issues. How can I create this type of result so that it is the same in both large and small screens? (obviously in smaller screens I would want a smaller font size and thus background color, but to keep the same overall vertical header.)

Also, I tried setting this up with two H tags but couldn't get the text to justify to the right. Only when I created the LI tags was I able to get the text to justify to the right where I wanted it.

```
<section id="testimonials" class="testimonials">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <div class="section-header">
                <ul class="list-unstyled rotated-text">
                    <li class="headerTitle">Testimonials</li> 
                    <li class="header-highlight">Dry Cleaning Station</li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div> <!--end col-lg-6-->
    </div> <!--end row-->
</div> <!--end container-->
```

```
.testimonials {
background-color: #181f17;
}

.rotated-text {
    background-color: #808080;

}

.section-header {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
 -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
   -o-transform: rotate(90deg); 
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
margin: 88px 0 90px -75px;
}

.headerTitle {
font-family: 'Novecento-Light';
color: #fff;
font-size: 28pt;  
float: right;
line-height: 24pt;
}

.header-highlight {
font-family: 'Novecento-Light';
color: #f6f5a3;
font-size: 18pt;
white-space: nowrap; 
float: right;
}

.col-lg-1 {
background-color: #305e6d;
height: 368px;
margin: 90px 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/popflier/0fc8gg2c/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not clear what you're after as the text disappears at large screen sizes. Should the text be contained by the blue box? What is a "vertical header"? Maybe an image would help.

Comment: Please tell us what you want to accomplih? Text be left of the screen?

Comment: Why would you use the grid system for this? Anyway... you're using the col-lg which only works on 1200px and up, use col-sm-1 or col-xs-1 or don't use the grid system at all, it's not for every thing. Plus, don't put margins, like you have on a column.

Comment: If you look at the JSFiddle link that Matty posted then you can see what I am wanting. If there's a different or better way that I should be doing this then please let me know. Like I said, I am learning and I want to learn how to code well and properly. If I am doing something wrong then please tell me. I changed the margins on the column because after I spent 4 hours trying everything else I could think of this was the only way I could get it to work. BTW...this is just an excerpt of code from a much larger website that I am coding for myself in Bootstrap. That's why I'm using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

First step: change `col-lg-1` to `col-xs-1`

Second step: make font smaller on smaller screens (use media queries).

http://jsfiddle.net/t5kL9yd7/

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was wanting! So the only thing you changed was the col-lg-1 to col-xs-1 on both the HTML and the CSS? Thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed, more about responsive grid here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

Comment: Matty, I've done what you have said and I have media queries setup for xs and sm devices. I noticed that if I enlarge the window past 480px that the header breaks until it reaches the next media query @ 768px. How can I fix this so that my vertical header won't break inbetween these two sizes? I've setup a JSFiddle here so that you can see the problem: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/popflier/0fc8gg2c/3/)

Comment: You put 2 intervals: "up to 480" and "767 and more", so there is an empty gap between 480 and 767. Change first to `@media (max-width: 767px)` and the second to `@media (min-width: 768px)`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the grid system here. It's a lot of html classes that you don't need and very messy. Also use transform-orgin. It's cleaner. Then just use media queries to make the font size smaller and the .bg and the rotated text adjustments.

### DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7x4zn2d1/

Answers to the comments in this thread:

If you look at any of the examples on GetBootstrap.com, GetBootstrap.com itself, all of the showcase sites, and most every Bootstrap theme on the planet, they all use custom CSS, added classes, more jQuery scripts. Bootstrap is a framework using CSS and JS. It is not CSS itself, or HTML, or JS, it uses these technologies. You would add to a site built with Bootstrap or take from it (that's why the customizer on GetBootstrap.com allows you to pick and choose).

Whether or not to use the Bootstrap grid system or other component based on experience. Generally, if it takes a ton of wrappers and lots of over-writing the Bootstrap classes, it's not worth it. But what consists of "lots" is subjective. If you use a framework it's best to explore the documentation, and their examples. If there is a similar looking component, then use that as your starting point. As you learn CSS and gain more experience, you will know what to use and what not to use and what is needed to be added.

**HTML**

```
<section id="testimonials" class="testimonials">
   <div class="section-header">
      <h3 class="headerTitle">Testimonials</h3>
      <h4 class="header-highlight">Dry Cleaning Station</h4>
   </div>
   <span class="bg"></span>
   <div class="content">
      <div class="content-inner">
         Content goes here.
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
<!--end section-->
```

**CSS**

```
.testimonials {
    background-color: #181f17;
    position: relative;
    height:400px;
}
.section-header {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left:-105px;
}
.testimonials .bg {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    left: 3%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #305e6d;
}
.section-header * {
    margin: 0
}
.headerTitle {
    font-family: 'Novecento-Light';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 28pt;
    line-height: 24pt;
}
.header-highlight {
    font-family: 'Novecento-Light';
    color: #f6f5a3;
    font-size: 18pt;
}
.testimonials .content {
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 3%;
}
.testimonials .content-inner {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 120px
}
```

Comment: So if the rest of the site is in Bootstrap and this section is not, will that affect how the site responds on devices of varying sizes? In all of the Bootstrap and HTML courses that I have taken no one has ever said that you could just use Bootstrap or HTML where needed. The instructors have always used Bootstrap for the entire site or not at all and only HTML/CSS. Is the best approach for optimized, clean code to only use the Bootstrap grid system in areas where it's needed and then use HTML/CSS for sections like this? How do I know when to use one and not the other? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I answered this in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks Christina. I appreciate you taking the time to explain this to me. I've spent a lot of time on the getbootstrap site and taking courses on Udemy and Learnable.com in both HTML/CSS and Bootstrap. I used to code Flash sites back in the day (AS2 only.) Who knew that Apple and Adobe would be so difficult that Flash would disappear almost entirely. Learning frameworks and HTML/CSS/JS/PHP will just take me some time to process as I'm a visual person. However, I do thank you for your assistance.